# What word meaning "random" was used before the word "random" got popularized?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

In the [What is Random?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rIy0xY99a0) vlog of the Vsauce channel, Michael says (start from 3:25):

> In the 1300s, random meant running or at great speed. Later, it would be used to describe things that have no definite purpose. It wasn't until the 1800s that random took on a particular mathematical definition. Then in the 1970s, MIT's student paper popularised the use of the word random to simply mean strange.

So, it must after 1970s that the word "random" started to have the meaning as we know today. So before that, what word was used instead, both for mathematicians/scientists and normal people?

And why did the word "random" spread out, when there was already another exactly term for that?

Comment: We have at least [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) (Pearson, [1905](http://www.e-m-h.org/Pear05.pdf)).

Comment: Also [random straight line](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspl.1867.0054) (Crofton, 1867), [random distribution](https://archive.org/stream/logicofchance029416mbp#page/n131) (Venn, 1888).

Comment: Also [random line, random point, random chord, random radius](https://books.google.com/books?id=3gYAAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA65&dq=random) (Godfray, 1867).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say **hazard** or **hasard** (or for an adjective, **fortuitous** or **fortuit**), as in

- C. Huygens, [Du calcul dans les jeux de **hasard**](http://dbnl.nl/tekst/huyg003oeuv14_01/huyg003oeuv14_01_0004.php) (Manuscript, 1656-1657).
- A. Furetière, [Dictionnaire Universel](https://books.google.com/books?id=3blKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT140) (Leers, 1690): "**Hasard**. f.m. Cas **fortuit**, ce qui arrive sans cause apparente ou nécessaire. (...) Ce mot vient de l'Espagnol [*azar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cnlFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT82&dq=Azar), qui signifie un *as*, et qui se prend aussi pour le *hasard* du dé."
- J. Arbuthnot, [Of the Laws of Chance, or, A Method of Calculation of the **Hazards** of Game](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=eebo;idno=A25748) (London, 1692) (a translation of Huygens' 1657 *De Ratiociniis in Ludo Aleae*).
- P. R. de Montmort, [Essay d'Analyse sur les Jeux de **Hazard**](http://dx.doi.org/10.3931/e-rara-5352) (Paris, 1708).
- J. Bernoulli, [Mémoire sur un problème de la doctrine du **hazard**](https://books.google.com/books?id=LG1UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA384), Hist. Acad. Roy. Berlin **1768** 384-408.
- P. S. de Laplace, [Mémoire sur les suites récurro-récurrentes et sur leurs usages dans la theorie des **hasards**](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k77596b/f10), Mém. Acad. Roy. Sci. Paris **6** (1774) 353-371.
- J. L. Lagrange, [Recherches sur les suites récurrentes dont les termes varient de plusieurs manières différentes, ou sur l'intégration des équations linéaires aux différences finies et partielles; et sur l'usage de ces équations dans la théorie des **hasards**](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bbaw/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=03-nouv/1775&seite:int=265), Nouv. Mém. Acad. Roy. Sci. Berlin **1775** 183-272.
- P. Prévost, [Sur les principes de la théorie des gains **fortuits**](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bbaw/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=03-nouv/1780&seite:int=501), Nouv. Mém. Acad. Roy. Sci. Berlin **1780** 430-472. ([Review](https://books.google.com/books?id=cQIwAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA19&dq=fortuitous): "The art of calculating **fortuitous** events is not above a century and a half old.")

*At random* (which seems to have been originally an [artillery](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ru-o5SnehxkC&pg=PT533&dq=random) [expression](https://books.google.com/books?id=CFBGAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT700&dq=random)) translates into *au hasard* in [Boyer](https://books.google.com/books?id=1IZaAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT455&dq=at%20random) (1711) and again in Laplace's [System of the World](https://books.google.com/books?id=f7Kv2iFUNJoC&pg=PA359&dq=random) (1809; [original](https://archive.org/stream/ed6expositiondusy00lapl#page/444)); the phrase *to hazard at random* is found in [Voltaire](https://books.google.com/books?id=uzlfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA132&dq=random) (1760) and [Adams](https://books.google.com/books?id=SXQSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA309&dq=random) (1794).

---

**Edit.** I now believe that the *adjective* you are really after is the French [**aléatoire**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/al%C3%A9atoire) or its German equivalent [**zufällig**](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/zuf%C3%A4llig.html) (whichever came first), as in

- événement aléatoire (Lacroix [1816](https://books.google.com/books?id=yg8OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA260&dq=al%C3%A9atoires#v=onepage&q=al%C3%A9atoires), Cournot [1843](https://books.google.com/books?id=_fk3AAAAMAAJ&q=%22%C3%A9v%C3%A9nement%20al%C3%A9atoire%22))
- zufällige Werthe (Hauber [1830](https://books.google.com/books?id=LiIFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA26&dq=zuf%C3%A4lligen))
- zufällige Ereignisse (Cournot [1849](https://books.google.com/books?id=AP8GAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=zuf%C3%A4lligen), Herr [1887](https://books.google.com/books?id=hENLAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22zuf%C3%A4lligen%20Ereignisses%22), Bernoulli [1899](https://books.google.com/books?id=i1ReAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA73&dq=zuf%C3%A4lligen), Czuber [1901](https://books.google.com/books?id=g5cjAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA764&dq=zuf%C3%A4lligen), v. Mangoldt [1911](https://books.google.com/books?id=e7NXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA36&dq=zuf%C3%A4lligen))
- zufällige Grösse (Hagen [1867](https://books.google.com/books?id=g-cGAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22zuf%C3%A4lligen%22#v=onepage&q=%22zuf%C3%A4lligen%22), Kolmogorov [1933](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-49888-6))
- nombre aléatoire (Fréchet [1924](https://books.google.com/books?id=eUBtAAAAMAAJ&q=al%C3%A9atoire))
- variable aléatoire (Borel [1925](https://books.google.com/books?id=njDvAAAAMAAJ&q=%22variable+al%C3%A9atoire%22)).

It would be interesting if you could pinpoint when "in the 1800s" the adjective *random* took on a mathematical meaning comparable to the above.

Comment: well, if you can, can you tell why does "random" got spread out while there was already the word "hazard"?

Comment: @Ooker Maybe because unlike "hazard", "random" works as an adjective?

Comment: I notice that you have added the *fortuitous* word, but don't see any reference in your answer. Can you add that?

Comment: @Ooker I had no reference to offer, other than the occurrence of *fortuit* in the Furetière quote above: unlike *hazard*, I'm not finding it used in early probability literature. FWIW, [this 1767 history of astronomy](https://books.google.com/books?id=jFQ_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA276&dq=fortuitous+random) speaks of "*random* or *fortuitous* irregularities", and [this 1768 dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=bXsCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PP445&dq=fortuitous+hazard) defines *hazard* as "*fortuitous hap*."

Comment: Your earliest English examples are from the 18th century. Have a look at my answer, which traces this usage back to the 15th.

Comment: @fdb I focused my answer on references *in the mathematics literature*, where "random" seems to have appeared rather late (1800s according to the OP). But you're absolutely right, the question also asks about "*normal people*" usage.

Answer (score 4):

I do not quite understand whether this is a question about history of science or about English usage. The Oxford English Dictionary points out that the phrase "at random" (earlier: "randon") occurs in English since the 16th century with this meaning:

> haphazardly, without aim, purpose, or fixed principle; heedlessly, carelessly; (also) erratically, indiscriminately, unsystematically

For example in this quotation from 1543:

> A certaine licenciousnes, or leude libertie..to ronne at randon hither, and thyther, through the wyde worlde perteygninge to no body.